# example of "really" non-existent transferred model structure

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories

I am looking for an example where a transferred model structure fails to exist, *even if one is willing to work with semi-model category.* But let me be more precise:

Let's say I have a combinatorial model category $C$, a locally presentable category $D$ and an adjunction :

$$ L: C \rightleftarrows D : U$$

A classical (at least - mentioned on the nLab) necessary and sufficient condition (in this case) for the existence of a transferred model structure on $D$ is that one has the following two:

**(A)** For every object $X \in D$ such that $U(X)$ is fibrant, there exists a "path object"
$X \overset{a}{\to} P \overset{p}{\to} X \times X$ such that $U(a)$ is a weak equivalence and $U(p)$ is a fibration.

**(B)** There exists a "fibrant replacement" functor and natural transformation $X \overset{a_x}{\to} FX$ on $D$, such that $U(FX)$ is fibrant and $U(a_x)$ is a weak equivalence.

I know examples where condition (B) fails, but I can't find an example where (A) fails. Do you know one ?

Some details and motivations:

In practice, it appears that condition (A) is often almost free and condition (B) is the hard one. For example, if $C$ is a simplicial model category, $D$ is simplicially enriched (with cotensor) and the adjunction is a simplicial adjunction, you can take $P$ to be the cotensor $P = X^{\Delta[1]}$. The same applies with other enrichement.

Now, it also appears that condition (A) is sufficient to build a "transferred model structure" on D, at least if one is willing to work with right semi-model category and slightly generalizing what one means by transferred model structure. So failure of condition (B) isn't really a deal breaker, but just an additional hassle.

This being said, I can't find a single example where condition (A) fails.

Comment: You're talking about injectively inducing a model structure. Are you also interested in the dual situation of projectively inducing a model structure?

Comment: I havn't really thought about it, so that's not really what I'm after, but if you know one such example, that might give some ideas (at least as a non-combinatorial example). Also I'm curious about your use of "injective" here, I don't know if there is a standard terminology for this, but I would rather call this projective (because projective model structure or of this kind). Where does it come from ?

Comment: Oh I see -- I just got confused by which arrow was drawn on top of which one. I totally agree that you're talking about projectively inducing rather than injectively inducing.

Comment: Ah Sorry, I see it now. I've changed the order of the arrow !

Comment: I don't know if you are interested by the opposite case: the left adjoint $\rm{SemiCat}\to \rm{Cat}$ from small semicategories to small categories which adds identity maps does not left induce on $\rm{SemiCat}$ a model structure by starting from the canonical model structure of $\rm{Cat}$.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but see [this talk](https://www.msri.org/seminars/25038) by Emily Riehl for an interesting example of a model structure where the weak factorization systems are both transferred but the weak equivalences are not. I suppose it probably fits your bill... [slides](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/MSRI-cubes.pdf).

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher Thanks, that a very nice example, that's exactly the dual of what I'm after.

Comment: @TimCampion I just watched the talk and I'm not sure what transfer you are refering too ? Also it seems to me the model structure under consideration are not combinatorial but only accessible.

Comment: @SimonHenry Sorry if I sent you on a wild goose chase, I don't remember what exactly was in that talk, all I remember appreciating was that there did exist some adjunction along which one could view the two wfs as being transferred, without the weak equivalences being "levelwise". I can ask Emily to explain that bit again and report back.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't think that was in the talk, but I can definitely imagine there might be a situation like this in this picture, I'm just not sure where. If it is that the weak equivalence are only define by transfer "beween fibrant object" then it is fairly classical and don't really answer my question, but if this is something more complicated that can be of interest

Comment: Will a consequence be that the adjunction becomes a Quillen adjunction? If so, it would suffice to take a monadic adjunction for which the monad doesn't send trivial cofibrations to weak equivalences. An example would be the symmetric functor on chain complexes of $R$-modules (projective model structure), for $R$ not containing $\mathbb{Q}$; all objects are fibrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual example in operad theory is when $C$ is a combinatorial, monoidal model category and $D$ is the category of commutative monoids in $C$. Unless $C$ satisfies a strong condition (that in my thesis, I called the *commutative monoid axiom*) guaranteeing symmetric powers are homotopically well-behaved, $D$ won't even have a semi-model structure.

For example, if $C = Ch(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is chain complexes over a field $k$ of characteristic p, then it is easy to show that $D$ can't have a transferred semi-model structure. You know that, if it did, then the generating trivial cofibrations would be of the form $Sym(J)$ where $J$ is the set of generating trivial cofibrations in $C$, and $Sym$ is the free commutative monoid function (L in your notation). Recall that maps in $J$ look like $0\to D(n)$ where $D(n)$ is the chain complex with one copy of $k$ in degrees $n$ and $n-1$, and identity boundary map.

Let's be quite explicit. Take $p=2$. Then $Sym(0)=k \to Sym(D(n))$ is not a weak equivalence, because if $y\in D(n)$ is non-zero then $y^2 \in Sym(D(n))$ is a cycle of degree $2n$ which is not a boundary. This is Example 3.7 in [Model Categories and Simplicial Methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609537).

Comment: Oh... I should have known this one ! Sorry about this. I actually discarded it because I thought is was a simplicially enriched enriched adjunction... but it is not, I was just being confused. My mistake was that if C is a (nice enough) simplicially enriched category then monoid in C is indeed also simplicial... but that only work if you take monoid for the cartesian structure (and product are compatible to the simplicial enrichement), not monoid for another tensor product...

Answer (score 3):

I expand my comment about the dual case.

1. ${\rm SemiCat}$ is the category of small [semicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory).
2. ${\rm Cat}$ is the category of small [categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category).

Note that every set can be viewed as a small semicategory without morphisms. We consider the functor $\mathbf{I}:{\rm SemiCat}\to {\rm Cat}$ which adds an identity map. Its right adjoint is the forgetful functor which forgets the identity maps. We consider the [canonical model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat) of ${\rm Cat}$ which is characterized as follows:

1. The cofibrations are the functors injective on objects.
2. The weak equivalences are the equivalences of categories.

Observe that when $f:A\to B$ is a morphism of semicategories and $B$ is a set (i.e. has no morphisms), then $A$ is a set. Therefore $R:\{0,1\}\to \{0\}$ is a trivial fibration in the left-induced model structure because it satisfies the RLP w.r.t. all injective set maps. But $\mathbf{I}(R)$ is not an equivalence of categories. Therefore the left-induced model structure does not exist by Proposition 2.1.4 of [A necessary and suﬃcient condition for induced model structures](https://doi.org/doi:10.1112/topo.12011). The dual of (B) is satisfied because all objects are cofibrant. Therefore the dual of (A) is not satisfied otherwise the left-induced model structure would exist by Theorem 2.2.1 of [A necessary and suﬃcient condition for induced model structures](https://doi.org/doi:10.1112/topo.12011). See also [Lifting accessible model structures](https://doi.org/doi:10.1112/topo.12123).

Comment: Thansk. There is something event better with this exemple : a map $u$ su ch that $I(u)$ is an equivalence has to be an isomorphism, so if one tries to transfer we end up with the same class of cofibrations and trivial cofibrations and no weak equivalences.